# AngularStrap Popover using trigger focus on img

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I am using the Popover AngularStrap using the trigger focus on a . The problem is that this trigger just works in a button element, however, the rest of the triggers can be used in a , Is there a way to make it works in a image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<a href="javascript:" title="{{popover.title}}" data-content="{{popover.content}}" data-template="popover/docs/popover.tpl.demo.html" data-animation="am-flip-x" bs-popover>
<img src="/my/image/path" />
</a>
```